# Is there a straightforward way to sort with multikey and insert to a slice in Golang?

Tags: go

I have function in python which looks like below

```
def reconstructQueue(self, people: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        people = sorted(people, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
        ans = []
        for a in people:
            ans.insert(a[1], a)
        return ans
```

Two things in above function.
1. Sort two dimensional array with multikeys x[0](descending order) and x[1](ascending order)
2. Insert an element in the array through a loop

Input: [[7,0], [4,4], [7,1], [5,0], [6,1], [5,2]]

I couldn't find an easy or straight forward way of implementing this logic in Golang. Can someone help me out to translate this code in Go way?

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type pair struct {
    x int
    y int
}

// print: prints the list
func print(l *list.List) {
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", e.Value)
    }
}

// do: does all the important operations
func do(queue []pair) *list.List {
    sort.Slice(queue, func(i, j int) bool {
        // If values are equal for first field then sort on
        // the basis of second field (ascending order)
        if queue[i].x == queue[j].x {
            return queue[i].y < queue[j].y
        }
        // Else sort on the basis of first field (decreasing order)
        return queue[i].x > queue[j].x
    })
    // Creates a list
    ans := list.New()
    for i := range queue {
        elem, ix, ixMark := &list.Element{}, 0, queue[i].y
        // Loops around to find the pos to fit in based on second field of element
        for elem = ans.Front(); elem != nil; elem = elem.Next() {
            if ix == ixMark {
                break
            }
            ix++
        }
        if elem == nil {
            // Add if list is empty
            ans.PushBack(queue[i])
        } else {
            // Add before the marked element
            ans.InsertBefore(queue[i], elem)
        }
    }
    return ans
}

func main() {
    elems := []pair{
        {7, 0},
        {4, 4},
        {7, 1},
        {5, 0},
        {6, 1},
        {5, 2},
    }
    queue := do(elems)
    print(queue)
    // Output:
    // {5 0}
    // {7 0}
    // {5 2}
    // {6 1}
    // {4 4}
    // {7 1}
}
```

The code is commented so that you can understand. So basically a combination of slice and list can help you achieve the same. No doubt there might be simpler, shorter ways to do the same in Go.

My implementation is quite a simple one.